# Terminal emulator that copies on select

Tags: terminal, macos

I'm a new Mac user (macOS Sierra on MacBook pro).

Coming from Windows, I used PuTTY as my terminal emulator which was fairly simple but quite useful.

I'm looking for a terminal emulation program that copies text to the clipboard upon selection (and not requiring my to hit <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>), like in PuTTY.

Is there such an app?

Thank you.
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iTerm2](http://iterm2.com/) has this functionality.

It's actually really easy to use and works exactly like you describe - you select your type and then middle click to paste within iTerm.

iTerm2 has many more features that make it far and away better than PuTTY and the best part is that it's free (as in beer) like PuTTY.

[image]

Above screenshot, I have selected the content of my Guest directory.  No clicks or keyboard shortcuts have been pressed.

In the image below, I simply press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> and paste it from the clipboard to TextEdit.  This is out of the box functionality - I haven't made any modifications to key combinations within iTerm2.

[image]

Comment: Hi, 
it's not quite what it does. when you mark text in iTerm2 it isn't copied to the clipboard (cmd+v won't paste anything). If you middle click it copies & pastes but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require me to switch between the keyboard and the mouse.

Comment: I just tested it and it works exactly as described.

Comment: You mark something, hit cmd+v and it pastes the marked text?

Comment: Yup.  Just did it again and took screen shots.

Comment: Yep, you are right. don't know how I missed it previously.
Thank you!